# In Angular, how do I resolve the modal not to be closed, when client clicks outside of it?

Tags: html, angular, modal-dialog

I've read several Q&A-s about it, all suggested a quite simple solution: to put a

```
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

in the HTML tag of the button, which is responsible for the modal opening. For me, the button is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger m-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" (click)="onDelete(object.id)"><fa-icon [icon]="faTrash"></fa-icon></button>
```

and the complete modal is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <!-- <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Biztosan törölni akarod?</h5> -->
        <button type="button" #closeButton class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Biztosan törölni akarod?</h5>
        <p class="text-center">A törlés megerősítésével az adatbázisból is eltávolításra kerül a rekord.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal" (click)="confirmDelete()">Törlés</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" (click)="declineDelete()">Visszavonás</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but every time I press ESC, or click outside of the modal, it just closes. I also tried to manage it from TS, with a `@ViewChild modal` (by refering to the modal DOM div), and a `dialog: MatDialog` property, then, in the `onDelete()` method, which is called when pressing the `Delete` button, I simply typed `this.modal.open(dialog, { disableClose: true });`, it did not work either. I'd prefer to just resolve it from the HTML though. Did i miss something? (I'm using angular 14.1.1 and bootstrap v5)

Comment: please share a stackblitz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backdrop has to be set to static so the modal will not close when clicking outside it but it is set as `data-bs-backdrop="static"`  instead of `data-backdrop="static"`

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Launch static backdrop modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```